# PHP redirect form to URL not working

Tags: php, redirect

So I'm trying to use this http://www.formget.com/how-to-redirect-a-url-php-form/ as an RSVP form.

Ideally, entering the right code on (http://baby.engquist.com/invite/) will lead you to a google form. However, when I enter any code (right or wrong) and press the button, it simply refreshes back to the /invite page.

My code is as follows:

```
<p style="text-align: center;">
  <form action="index.php" id="#form" method="post" name="#form">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="large-3 columns large-centered">
        <div class="row collapse">
          <div class="small-10 columns">
            <input id="code" name="code" placeholder="Enter the code to RSVP." type="text" >
          </div>
          <div class="small-2 columns">
            <input id='btn' name="submit" type='submit' class="button prefix" value='Go'>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <?php
    include "redirect.php";
    ?>

  </form>
</p>
```

And the included redirect.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  // Fetching variables of the form which travels in URL
  $code = $_POST['code'];
  if($code ='show620')
  {
    // To redirect form on a particular page
    header("Location:http://google.com/");
  } else {
    print "Oops that's not the right code. Try again!"; 
  }
?>
```

Thanks so much for any help!

Comment: what is the exact error you are getting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have action attribute pointing to file where you do processing after submitting. In your case its `redirect.php`

Use :

```
<form action="redirect.php" > ............
```

And dont include `redirect.php` at the bottom of the form.

Comment: I did this and now it's simply redirecting to redirect.php? I'm assuming that means something's wrong with the redirect.php code.

Comment: do you get  `print "Oops that's not the right code. Try again!"; ` ? inside your if just before `header("Location:http://google.com/");` , print ->     `echo "in if";`

Comment: I figured out - I was missing another } for the initial if. thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to write `ob_start();` on top of your page and die(); after `header("Location:http://google.com/");` in redirect.php

Comment: on top of redirect.php or the /invite page?

Comment: on top of invite.php like this <?php ob_start();  ?>

Answer (score 0):

The php header redirect only works if it's called from a page that is completely blank.  You have to change your form action to "redirect.php" and simply get rid of the code at the bottom of your html.